# Issues in custom filtering boolean value in primeng Table

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using primeng Table for displaying data in my Angular app,
the issue i have right now is i have to use filter but with conditions, for example if user type 0, 1, or 2, i have to display data based on this, what i am trying is this

```
        if(value == 0) {
            table.filter(value, fieldName, 'equals');
        } else if(value == 1) {
            table.filter(0, fieldName, 'gt');
            table.filter(false, 'array[0].fieldName',  'equals');
        } else if(value == 2) {
            table.filter(0, fieldName, 'gt');
            table.filter(true, 'array[0].fieldName',  'equals');
        }
```

if user type 0 its filtering fine, but the issue is when he type 1 or 2 because i have to filter from 2 fields, i am not sure what i am trying to do is possible in primeng or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table.filter(...)` works on a single column.

It is designed to filter the data on a particular column. The following is the type definition of the `filter` function:

```
filter(value: any, field: any, matchMode: any): void;
```

But you are on the right path as it is possible to set different filters, one on each column, which are then combined with `AND` to filter the data of the table.

For example the following function can filter using multiple columns:

```
filter(dt) {
  dt.filter('Blue', 'color', 'equals');
  dt.filter('Bmw', 'brand', 'equals');
}
```

Here's an example of a template:

```
<p-table #dt [value]="cars">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
     <tr>
      <th>
        Color
      </th>
      <th>
        Brand
      </th>
     </tr>
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-car>
     <tr>
      <td>{{car.color}}</td>
      <td>{{car.brand}}</td>
     </tr>
   </ng-template>
</p-table>

<button (click)="filter(dt)">Get Blue Bmw</button>
```

And a complete component:

```
export class MyComponent {
  cars: {
    color: string;
    brand: string;
  }[];

  constructor() {
    this.cars = [{
      color: "blue",
      brand: "bmw"
    },{
      color: "red",
      brand: "bmw"
    }];
  }

  filter(dt) {
    dt.filter('Blue', 'color', 'equals');
    dt.filter('Bmw', 'brand', 'equals');
  }
}
```

The button will apply the filter on multiple columns which will result in data 
 being filtered with `color equals Blue` `AND` `brand equals Bmw`.

**Edit:** It works the same for `boolean`.

```
cars: {
  color: string;
  brand: string;
  enable: boolean;
}[];

filter(dt) {
  dt.filter('Blue', 'color', 'equals');
  dt.filter('Bmw', 'brand', 'equals');
  dt.filter(true, 'enable', 'equals');
}
```

In the code you pasted `'array[0].fieldName'` is treated as a literal due to the quotes, therefore it looks for a field name "array[0].fieldName" and does not evaluate it.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i am using table not p-table and it looks like the issue is boolean value because i try same code on text fields and it works for 2 columns

Comment: our code is same can you please confirm code for boolean value, i am applying this on boolean field

Comment: how i comare boolean value ?

Comment: @MuhammadArslan I've updated the answer to answer your question.

Comment: thanks for your answer, then how i can add my field because its inside another array?

Comment: i have another object, and it works fine like this, object.fieldName but another field that is inside array not works like this, array[0].fieldName, not sure how i can pass that field from array

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What is the result of `array[0].fieldName`?
The result of it will be used as the column hence the property name to compare data to.

Comment: actually this is the field event_parameter[0].event_grade, when i check filters in console it shows filtering by this field but not load data

Comment: this works fine, venue_instance.state_name as a field name